# Why does the tooltip for my range slider defy expectations and present an unexpected display glitch?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip, rangeslider

So, in my bootstrap 5 modal, I have a range slider. I added a tooltip to my three dynamic range sliders. After i add them, the tooltips overflow on the right side ( displaying incorrectly ). I attempted to make it on absolute positions, but it isn't working.

[image]

I want my tooltip to behave similarly to a standard range slider tooltip. I attempted to fix it, but because it is dynamic, those three range slider tooltips are showing the other right side of each range slider.

My code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <style>

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');

.middle {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
}

.slider {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    height: var(--2, 8px);
}
.slider > .track {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #E5E7EB;
}
.slider > .range {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 25%;
    right: 25%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #1C64F2;
}
.slider > .thumb {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(98,0,238,.1);
    transition: box-shadow .3s ease-in-out;

    stroke-width: 1px;
    stroke: var(--gray-200, #E5E7EB);
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08));
}
.slider > .thumb.left {
    left: 25%;
    transform: translate(-15px, -10px);
}
.slider > .thumb.right {
    right: 25%;
    transform: translate(15px, -10px);
}


input[type=range] {
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    pointer-events: all;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 0 none;
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    background-color: #1c64f2;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: var(--05, 2px) var(--2, 8px);
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    opacity: 1;
    top: -40px !important;
}



.modal-dialog {
    max-width: 720px;
    padding: 4px;
}


/* Max Result Start */
.max-result {
    margin-top: 16px;
}
.max-result label {
    color: #000;
    font-family: Inter;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 150%;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.max-result .form-control {
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: #F9FAFB;
    border-color: #D1D5DB;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
.max-result .form-control::placeholder {
    color: #6B7280;
}

.price-range-section {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E7EB;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
}
.price-range-section label:first-child {
    color: #000;
    font-family: Inter;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 150%; 
    margin-bottom: 26px;
}
.modal-body .price-range-section:nth-child(2) {
    margin-top: 16px;
}
.modal-body-pad {
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}


    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop">
    Launch static backdrop modal
  </button>
  
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade filter-modal" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header range-modal-header">
          <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="staticBackdropLabel">Filters</h1>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body modal-body-pad">

            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link active" id="blockA-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#blockA">Basic</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" id="blockB-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#blockB">Advanced</a>
                </li>
              </ul>

              <div class="tab-content mt-2">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="blockA">
                  <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="price-range-section">
                                <label for="Price Range">Price Range</label>
                                <div class="middle">    
                                    <div class="multi-range-slider">
                                        <input type="range" id="price-min-slider" min="0" max="100" value="25">
                                        <input type="range" id="price-max-slider" min="0" max="100" value="75">
                                
                                        <div class="slider">
                                            <div class="track"></div>
                                            <div class="range"></div>
                                            <div class="thumb left"></div>
                                            <div class="thumb right"></div>
                                        </div>

                                         <!-- Tooltips -->
                                         <div class="tooltip" id="tooltip-left"></div>
                                         <div class="tooltip" id="tooltip-right"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                
                            <div class="price-range-section">
                                <label for="Delivery Range">Delivery Time (Days)</label>
                                <div class="middle">    
                                    <div class="multi-range-slider multi-range-slider2">
                                        <input type="range" id="min-delivery-slider" min="0" max="100" value="25">
                                        <input type="range" id="max-delivery-slider" min="0" max="100" value="75">

                                        <div class="slider">
                                            <div class="track"></div>
                                            <div class="range"></div>
                                            <div class="thumb left"></div>
                                            <div class="thumb right"></div>
                                        </div>

                                        <!-- Tooltips -->
                                        <div class="tooltip" id="tooltip-left2"></div>
                                        <div class="tooltip" id="tooltip-right2"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="price-range-section mt-3">
                                <label for="Bid Range">Bid Count</label>
                                <div class="middle">    
                                    <div class="multi-range-slider multi-range-slider3">
                                        <input type="range" id="min-bid-slider" min="0" max="100" value="25">
                                        <input type="range" id="max-bid-slider" min="0" max="100" value="75">

                                        <div class="slider">
                                            <div class="track"></div>
                                            <div class="range"></div>
                                            <div class="thumb left"></div>
                                            <div class="thumb right"></div>
                                        </div>

                                        <!-- Tooltips -->
                                        <div class="tooltip" id="tooltip-left3"></div>
                                        <div class="tooltip" id="tooltip-right3"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
        
                        </div>
                        
            </div>
                    
            </div>
            </div>
                
        </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<script>
    //Range Price Slider Script Start / Price slider
    var PriceMinSlider = document.getElementById('price-min-slider');
      var PriceMaxSlider = document.getElementById('price-max-slider');

      var thumbLeft = document.querySelector('.slider > .thumb.left');
      var thumbRight = document.querySelector('.slider > .thumb.right');
      var range = document.querySelector('.slider > .range');

      var tooltipLeft = document.getElementById('tooltip-left');
      var tooltipRight = document.getElementById('tooltip-right');

      function setLeftValue() {
        var _this = PriceMinSlider,
          min = parseInt(_this.min),
          max = parseInt(_this.max);

        _this.value = Math.min(
          parseInt(_this.value),
          parseInt(PriceMaxSlider.value) - 1
        );

        var percent = ((_this.value - min) / (max - min)) * 100;

        thumbLeft.style.left = percent + '%';
        range.style.left = percent + '%';
        updateTooltipPosition();
      }

      setLeftValue();

      function setRightValue() {
        var _this = PriceMaxSlider,
          min = parseInt(_this.min),
          max = parseInt(_this.max);

        _this.value = Math.max(
          parseInt(_this.value),
          parseInt(PriceMinSlider.value) + 1
        );

        var percent = ((_this.value - min) / (max - min)) * 100;

        thumbRight.style.right = 100 - percent + '%';
        range.style.right = 100 - percent + '%';
        updateTooltipPosition();
      }

      setRightValue();

      function updateTooltipPosition() {
        var thumbLeftPosition = thumbLeft.getBoundingClientRect();
        var thumbRightPosition = thumbRight.getBoundingClientRect();

        tooltipLeft.style.display = 'block';
        tooltipLeft.style.left = thumbLeftPosition.left + 'px';
        tooltipLeft.style.top = thumbLeftPosition.bottom + 5 + 'px';
        tooltipLeft.innerHTML = PriceMinSlider.value;

        tooltipRight.style.display = 'block';
        tooltipRight.style.left = thumbRightPosition.left + 'px';
        tooltipRight.style.top = thumbRightPosition.bottom + 5 + 'px';
        tooltipRight.innerHTML = PriceMaxSlider.value;
      }
      PriceMinSlider.addEventListener('input', setLeftValue);
      PriceMaxSlider.addEventListener('input', setRightValue);

      PriceMinSlider.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
        thumbLeft.classList.add('active');
      });

      PriceMinSlider.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
        thumbLeft.classList.remove('active');
      });

      PriceMaxSlider.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
        thumbRight.classList.add('active');
      });

      PriceMaxSlider.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
        thumbRight.classList.remove('active');
      });
//Range Price Slider  Script End



// Range Delivery Slider Script
var MinDeliverySlider = document.getElementById('min-delivery-slider');
var MaxDeliverySlider = document.getElementById('max-delivery-slider');

var thumbLeft2 = document.querySelector('.multi-range-slider2 > .slider > .thumb.left');
var thumbRight2 = document.querySelector('.multi-range-slider2 > .slider > .thumb.right');
var range2 = document.querySelector('.multi-range-slider2 > .slider > .range');

var tooltipLeft2 = document.getElementById('tooltip-left2');
var tooltipRight2 = document.getElementById('tooltip-right2');

function setLeftValue2() {
    var _this = MinDeliverySlider,
        min = parseInt(_this.min),
        max = parseInt(_this.max);

    _this.value = Math.min(
        parseInt(_this.value),
        parseInt(MaxDeliverySlider.value) - 1
    );

    var percent = ((_this.value - min) / (max - min)) * 100;

    thumbLeft2.style.left = percent + '%';
    range2.style.left = percent + '%';
    updateTooltipPosition2();
}

setLeftValue2();

function setRightValue2() {
    var _this = MaxDeliverySlider,
        min = parseInt(_this.min),
        max = parseInt(_this.max);

    _this.value = Math.max(
        parseInt(_this.value),
        parseInt(MinDeliverySlider.value) + 1
    );

    var percent = ((_this.value - min) / (max - min)) * 100;

    thumbRight2.style.right = 100 - percent + '%';
    range2.style.right = 100 - percent + '%';
    updateTooltipPosition2();
}

setRightValue2();

function updateTooltipPosition2() {
    var thumbLeftPosition2 = thumbLeft2.getBoundingClientRect();
    var thumbRightPosition2 = thumbRight2.getBoundingClientRect();

    tooltipLeft2.style.display = 'block';
    tooltipLeft2.style.left = thumbLeftPosition2.left + 'px';
    tooltipLeft2.style.top = thumbLeftPosition2.bottom + 5 + 'px';
    tooltipLeft2.innerHTML = MinDeliverySlider.value;

    tooltipRight2.style.display = 'block';
    tooltipRight2.style.left = thumbRightPosition2.left + 'px';
    tooltipRight2.style.top = thumbRightPosition2.bottom + 5 + 'px';
    tooltipRight2.innerHTML = MaxDeliverySlider.value;
}

MinDeliverySlider.addEventListener('input', setLeftValue2);
MaxDeliverySlider.addEventListener('input', setRightValue2);

MinDeliverySlider.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
    thumbLeft2.classList.add('active');
});

MinDeliverySlider.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
    thumbLeft2.classList.remove('active');
});

MaxDeliverySlider.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
    thumbRight2.classList.add('active');
});

MaxDeliverySlider.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
    thumbRight2.classList.remove('active');
});


// Range Bid Slider Script
var MinBidSlider = document.getElementById('min-bid-slider');
var MaxBidSlider = document.getElementById('max-bid-slider');

var thumbLeft3 = document.querySelector('.multi-range-slider3 > .slider > .thumb.left');
var thumbRight3 = document.querySelector('.multi-range-slider3 > .slider > .thumb.right');
var range3 = document.querySelector('.multi-range-slider3 > .slider > .range');

var tooltipLeft3 = document.getElementById('tooltip-left3');
var tooltipRight3 = document.getElementById('tooltip-right3');

function setLeftValue3() {
    var _this = MinBidSlider,
        min = parseInt(_this.min),
        max = parseInt(_this.max);

    _this.value = Math.min(
        parseInt(_this.value),
        parseInt(MaxBidSlider.value) - 1
    );

    var percent = ((_this.value - min) / (max - min)) * 100;

    thumbLeft3.style.left = percent + '%';
    range3.style.left = percent + '%';
    updateTooltipPosition3();
}

setLeftValue3();

function setRightValue3() {
    var _this = MaxBidSlider,
        min = parseInt(_this.min),
        max = parseInt(_this.max);

    _this.value = Math.max(
        parseInt(_this.value),
        parseInt(MinBidSlider.value) + 1
    );

    var percent = ((_this.value - min) / (max - min)) * 100;

    thumbRight3.style.right = 100 - percent + '%';
    range3.style.right = 100 - percent + '%';
    updateTooltipPosition3();
}

setRightValue3();

function updateTooltipPosition3() {
    var thumbLeftPosition3 = thumbLeft3.getBoundingClientRect();
    var thumbRightPosition3 = thumbRight3.getBoundingClientRect();

    tooltipLeft3.style.display = 'block';
    tooltipLeft3.style.left = thumbLeftPosition3.left + 'px';
    tooltipLeft3.style.top = thumbLeftPosition3.bottom + 5 + 'px';
    tooltipLeft3.innerHTML = MinBidSlider.value;

    tooltipRight3.style.display = 'block';
    tooltipRight3.style.left = thumbRightPosition3.left + 'px';
    tooltipRight3.style.top = thumbRightPosition3.bottom + 5 + 'px';
    tooltipRight3.innerHTML = MaxBidSlider.value;
}

MinBidSlider.addEventListener('input', setLeftValue3);
MaxBidSlider.addEventListener('input', setRightValue3);

MinBidSlider.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
    thumbLeft3.classList.add('active');
});

MinBidSlider.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
    thumbLeft3.classList.remove('active');
});

MaxBidSlider.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
    thumbRight3.classList.add('active');
});

MaxBidSlider.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
    thumbRight3.classList.remove('active');
});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The values of `.getBoundingClientRect()` are relative to the top left corner of the viewport. When you apply the results of this call as-is onto the tooltips via the `.left` property, it would be relative to their nearest position parent . Thus we should "undo" this offset. We can get their respective position parents by reading `.offsetParent` property and then getting its top-left corner viewport relative values from its own `.getBoundingClientRect()`. Subtracting the `left` from the original `.getBoundingClientRect()` will give us a relative value that would exhibit the behavior I believe you are after:

```js
//Range Price Slider Script Start / Price slider
    var PriceMinSlider = document.getElementById('price-min-slider');
      var PriceMaxSlider = document.getElementById('price-max-slider');

      var thumbLeft = document.querySelector('.slider > .thumb.left');
      var thumbRight = document.querySelector('.slider > .thumb.right');
      var range = document.querySelector('.slider > .range');

      var tooltipLeft = document.getElementById('tooltip-left');
      var tooltipRight = document.getElementById('tooltip-right');

      function setLeftValue() {
        var _this = PriceMinSlider,
          min = parseInt(_this.min),
          max = parseInt(_this.max);

        _this.value = Math.min(
          parseInt(_this.value),
          parseInt(PriceMaxSlider.value) - 1
        );

        var percent = ((_this.value - min) / (max - min)) * 100;

        thumbLeft.style.left = percent + '%';
        range.style.left = percent + '%';
        updateTooltipPosition({ left: thumbLeft.style.left });
      }

      setLeftValue();

      function setRightValue() {
        var _this = PriceMaxSlider,
          min = parseInt(_this.min),
          max = parseInt(_this.max);

        _this.value = Math.max(
          parseInt(_this.value),
          parseInt(PriceMinSlider.value) + 1
        );

        var percent = ((_this.value - min) / (max - min)) * 100;

        thumbRight.style.right = 100 - percent + '%';
        range.style.right = 100 - percent + '%';
        updateTooltipPosition({ right: thumbRight.style.right });
      }

      setRightValue();

      function updateTooltipPosition({ left, right }) {
        var thumbLeftPosition = thumbLeft.getBoundingClientRect();
        var thumbRightPosition = thumbRight.getBoundingClientRect();
        
        tooltipLeft.style.display = 'block';
        if (left) tooltipLeft.style.left = left;
        tooltipLeft.style.top = thumbLeftPosition.bottom + 5 + 'px';
        tooltipLeft.innerHTML = PriceMinSlider.value;

        tooltipRight.style.display = 'block';
        if (right) tooltipRight.style.right = right;
        tooltipRight.style.top = thumbRightPosition.bottom + 5 + 'px';
        tooltipRight.innerHTML = PriceMaxSlider.value;
      }
      PriceMinSlider.addEventListener('input', setLeftValue);
      PriceMaxSlider.addEventListener('input', setRightValue);

      PriceMinSlider.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
        thumbLeft.classList.add('active');
      });

      PriceMinSlider.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
        thumbLeft.classList.remove('active');
      });

      PriceMaxSlider.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
        thumbRight.classList.add('active');
      });

      PriceMaxSlider.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
        thumbRight.classList.remove('active');
      });
//Range Price Slider  Script End



// Range Delivery Slider Script
var MinDeliverySlider = document.getElementById('min-delivery-slider');
var MaxDeliverySlider = document.getElementById('max-delivery-slider');

var thumbLeft2 = document.querySelector('.multi-range-slider2 > .slider > .thumb.left');
var thumbRight2 = document.querySelector('.multi-range-slider2 > .slider > .thumb.right');
var range2 = document.querySelector('.multi-range-slider2 > .slider > .range');

var tooltipLeft2 = document.getElementById('tooltip-left2');
var tooltipRight2 = document.getElementById('tooltip-right2');

function setLeftValue2() {
    var _this = MinDeliverySlider,
        min = parseInt(_this.min),
        max = parseInt(_this.max);

    _this.value = Math.min(
        parseInt(_this.value),
        parseInt(MaxDeliverySlider.value) - 1
    );

    var percent = ((_this.value - min) / (max - min)) * 100;

    thumbLeft2.style.left = percent + '%';
    range2.style.left = percent + '%';
    updateTooltipPosition2({ left: thumbLeft2.style.left });
}

setLeftValue2();

function setRightValue2() {
    var _this = MaxDeliverySlider,
        min = parseInt(_this.min),
        max = parseInt(_this.max);

    _this.value = Math.max(
        parseInt(_this.value),
        parseInt(MinDeliverySlider.value) + 1
    );

    var percent = ((_this.value - min) / (max - min)) * 100;

    thumbRight2.style.right = 100 - percent + '%';
    range2.style.right = 100 - percent + '%';
    updateTooltipPosition2({ right: thumbRight2.style.right });
}

setRightValue2();

function updateTooltipPosition2({ left, right }) {
    var thumbLeftPosition2 = thumbLeft2.getBoundingClientRect();
    var thumbRightPosition2 = thumbRight2.getBoundingClientRect();

    tooltipLeft2.style.display = 'block';
    if (left) tooltipLeft2.style.left = left;
    tooltipLeft2.style.top = thumbLeftPosition2.bottom + 5 + 'px';
    tooltipLeft2.innerHTML = MinDeliverySlider.value;

    tooltipRight2.style.display = 'block';
    if (right) tooltipRight2.style.right = right;
    tooltipRight2.style.top = thumbRightPosition2.bottom + 5 + 'px';
    tooltipRight2.innerHTML = MaxDeliverySlider.value;
}

MinDeliverySlider.addEventListener('input', setLeftValue2);
MaxDeliverySlider.addEventListener('input', setRightValue2);

MinDeliverySlider.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
    thumbLeft2.classList.add('active');
});

MinDeliverySlider.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
    thumbLeft2.classList.remove('active');
});

MaxDeliverySlider.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
    thumbRight2.classList.add('active');
});

MaxDeliverySlider.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
    thumbRight2.classList.remove('active');
});


// Range Bid Slider Script
var MinBidSlider = document.getElementById('min-bid-slider');
var MaxBidSlider = document.getElementById('max-bid-slider');

var thumbLeft3 = document.querySelector('.multi-range-slider3 > .slider > .thumb.left');
var thumbRight3 = document.querySelector('.multi-range-slider3 > .slider > .thumb.right');
var range3 = document.querySelector('.multi-range-slider3 > .slider > .range');

var tooltipLeft3 = document.getElementById('tooltip-left3');
var tooltipRight3 = document.getElementById('tooltip-right3');

function setLeftValue3() {
    var _this = MinBidSlider,
        min = parseInt(_this.min),
        max = parseInt(_this.max);

    _this.value = Math.min(
        parseInt(_this.value),
        parseInt(MaxBidSlider.value) - 1
    );

    var percent = ((_this.value - min) / (max - min)) * 100;

    thumbLeft3.style.left = percent + '%';
    range3.style.left = percent + '%';
    updateTooltipPosition3({ left: thumbLeft3.style.left });
}

setLeftValue3();

function setRightValue3() {
    var _this = MaxBidSlider,
        min = parseInt(_this.min),
        max = parseInt(_this.max);

    _this.value = Math.max(
        parseInt(_this.value),
        parseInt(MinBidSlider.value) + 1
    );

    var percent = ((_this.value - min) / (max - min)) * 100;

    thumbRight3.style.right = 100 - percent + '%';
    range3.style.right = 100 - percent + '%';
    updateTooltipPosition3({ right: thumbRight3.style.right });
}

setRightValue3();

function updateTooltipPosition3({ left, right }) {
    var thumbLeftPosition3 = thumbLeft3.getBoundingClientRect();
    var thumbRightPosition3 = thumbRight3.getBoundingClientRect();

    tooltipLeft3.style.display = 'block';
    if (left) tooltipLeft3.style.left = left;
    tooltipLeft3.style.top = thumbLeftPosition3.bottom + 5 + 'px';
    tooltipLeft3.innerHTML = MinBidSlider.value;

    tooltipRight3.style.display = 'block';
    if (right) tooltipRight3.style.right = right;
    tooltipRight3.style.top = thumbRightPosition3.bottom + 5 + 'px';
    tooltipRight3.innerHTML = MaxBidSlider.value;
}

MinBidSlider.addEventListener('input', setLeftValue3);
MaxBidSlider.addEventListener('input', setRightValue3);

MinBidSlider.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
    thumbLeft3.classList.add('active');
});

MinBidSlider.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
    thumbLeft3.classList.remove('active');
});

MaxBidSlider.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
    thumbRight3.classList.add('active');
});

MaxBidSlider.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
    thumbRight3.classList.remove('active');
});

[tooltipLeft, tooltipLeft2, tooltipLeft3].forEach(ele => ele.style.transform = 'translateX(-50%)');
[tooltipRight, tooltipRight2, tooltipRight3].forEach(ele => ele.style.transform = 'translateX(50%)');
```

```css
@import url('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');
@import url('https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css');

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');

.middle {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
}

.slider {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    height: var(--2, 8px);
}
.slider > .track {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #E5E7EB;
}
.slider > .range {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 25%;
    right: 25%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #1C64F2;
}
.slider > .thumb {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(98,0,238,.1);
    transition: box-shadow .3s ease-in-out;

    stroke-width: 1px;
    stroke: var(--gray-200, #E5E7EB);
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08));
}
.slider > .thumb.left {
    left: 25%;
    transform: translate(-15px, -10px);
}
.slider > .thumb.right {
    right: 25%;
    transform: translate(15px, -10px);
}


input[type=range] {
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    pointer-events: all;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 0 none;
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    background-color: #1c64f2;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: var(--05, 2px) var(--2, 8px);
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    opacity: 1;
    top: -40px !important;
}



.modal-dialog {
    max-width: 720px;
    padding: 4px;
}


/* Max Result Start */
.max-result {
    margin-top: 16px;
}
.max-result label {
    color: #000;
    font-family: Inter;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 150%;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.max-result .form-control {
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: #F9FAFB;
    border-color: #D1D5DB;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
.max-result .form-control::placeholder {
    color: #6B7280;
}

.price-range-section {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E7EB;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
}
.price-range-section label:first-child {
    color: #000;
    font-family: Inter;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 150%; 
    margin-bottom: 26px;
}
.modal-body .price-range-section:nth-child(2) {
    margin-top: 16px;
}
.modal-body-pad {
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop">
    Launch static backdrop modal
  </button>
  
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade filter-modal" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header range-modal-header">
          <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="staticBackdropLabel">Filters</h1>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body modal-body-pad">

            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link active" id="blockA-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#blockA">Basic</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" id="blockB-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#blockB">Advanced</a>
                </li>
              </ul>

              <div class="tab-content mt-2">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="blockA">
                  <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="price-range-section">
                                <label for="Price Range">Price Range</label>
                                <div class="middle">    
                                    <div class="multi-range-slider">
                                        <input type="range" id="price-min-slider" min="0" max="100" value="25">
                                        <input type="range" id="price-max-slider" min="0" max="100" value="75">
                                
                                        <div class="slider">
                                            <div class="track"></div>
                                            <div class="range"></div>
                                            <div class="thumb left"></div>
                                            <div class="thumb right"></div>
                                        </div>

                                         <!-- Tooltips -->
                                         <div class="tooltip" id="tooltip-left"></div>
                                         <div class="tooltip" id="tooltip-right"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                
                            <div class="price-range-section">
                                <label for="Delivery Range">Delivery Time (Days)</label>
                                <div class="middle">    
                                    <div class="multi-range-slider multi-range-slider2">
                                        <input type="range" id="min-delivery-slider" min="0" max="100" value="25">
                                        <input type="range" id="max-delivery-slider" min="0" max="100" value="75">

                                        <div class="slider">
                                            <div class="track"></div>
                                            <div class="range"></div>
                                            <div class="thumb left"></div>
                                            <div class="thumb right"></div>
                                        </div>

                                        <!-- Tooltips -->
                                        <div class="tooltip" id="tooltip-left2"></div>
                                        <div class="tooltip" id="tooltip-right2"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="price-range-section mt-3">
                                <label for="Bid Range">Bid Count</label>
                                <div class="middle">    
                                    <div class="multi-range-slider multi-range-slider3">
                                        <input type="range" id="min-bid-slider" min="0" max="100" value="25">
                                        <input type="range" id="max-bid-slider" min="0" max="100" value="75">

                                        <div class="slider">
                                            <div class="track"></div>
                                            <div class="range"></div>
                                            <div class="thumb left"></div>
                                            <div class="thumb right"></div>
                                        </div>

                                        <!-- Tooltips -->
                                        <div class="tooltip" id="tooltip-left3"></div>
                                        <div class="tooltip" id="tooltip-right3"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
        
                        </div>
                        
            </div>
                    
            </div>
            </div>
                
        </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it possible to have the range slider tooltips on those pages display its thumb input value when the user first visits or opens the modal? When we open the modal, it is currently on the left side.

Comment: Yes, I don't see why it wouldn't be possible. If you need help with implementing that, consider posting a new question.

Comment: Is it feasible to include the solution in the code snippet you supplied? I am unable to post a question at this time. @Wongjn

Comment: Added, though really you should have waited until you are able to post a question.